# Nacos service registration issues

Tags: grpc-java, nacos

After batch restarting service, the registed service will drop one by one. After about 30 minutes, the service will regist successfully.

log:
nacos.common.remote.client.grpc.GrpcClient-server check fail, please check server ****, port 9848 is available, java.util.concurent.ExecutionException: com.alibaba.nacos.shaded.io.grpc.StatusRuntimeException: UNKNOWN
....
caused by: java.lang.illegalArgumentException: Invalid padding '4907232'. Padding must between be 0 and 256(inclusive)

nacos version: 2.2.3
nacos jdk: 8u332
cpu: arm64
sys: ASIANUX 7

Comment: After upgraded nacos from 1.4.2 to 2.2.3, this issue happened.